# How can I resolve this issue, I am unable to access my controller class methods from Postman or Browser?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, postman

I am running a simple Spring boot application, In console its running successfully. But when I am trying by postman it gives this error message.

```
{
"timestamp": "2020-07-26T04:22:15.626+00:00",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "",
"path": "/loginRegistration/user/"
```

}

My project structure is...
[image]

My Main class is

```
import org.example.controller.User;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        System.out.println("Welcome");
    }
}
```

My Controller is....

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import org.example.entity.Registration;
import org.example.model.UserDto;
import org.example.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class User {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerUser(@Validated UserDto userdto) throws JsonProcessingException {
        userService.registerUser(userdto);
        return "success";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getUserList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Registration> getUserList() {
        List<Registration> list = userService.getUserList();
        return list;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String test() {
        return "testing";
    }
}
```

Please guide me what changes need to be done to run on postman.

Answer (score 2):

> spring application name does not use as context path. You will have to
> define below property in your application.properties file to use
> 'loginRegistration' as your context path.

```
server.servlet.context-path=/loginRegistration
```

And now you can use it as /loginRegistration/user/

Let me know if that helps. Thanks

Comment: "loginRegistration" is my application name. I wrote in application.properties file.
 like spring.application.name=loginRegistration

Comment: `/user` it controller-level mapping. Try to add mapping for concrete method, i.e. `/loginRegistration/user/registration`

Comment: @VikramShekhawat: When you get chance please accept the answer so it can be useful to others. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure, you providing war name along with your given URL... And see packages should be under you main class... if not u have to add in main class using componentscan

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to what @Jimmy described is to define `@RequestMapping` in your User class as -

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/loginRegistration/user/")
public class User {
```